# How do you show/hide an element on a click event from js code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I used to use Jquery extensively. Now that I stumbled upon Angularjs, I am trying understand how it works and I have been really excited about the AutoMagic way it works. For example, am able to do the below process of hiding and showing few blocks just by using `ng-click`, `ng-hide` & `ng-show`.

```
<form id="signup-form" ng-submit="processForm()" ng-hide="showConfirm" >
    <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="name">
    <button type="submit"  id="submit" ng-click="showConfirm = ! showConfirm">Submit</button>
</form>

<div class="col-md-12 confirmation" ng-show="showConfirm">
        <h2 >Thanks alot for your feedback.</h1>
</div>
```

But, I am still wondering how can I do the same from code, say from a controller. In Jquery one way to do would be like:

```
$( "#submit" ).click(function() {
   $(".confirmation").show();
   $("#signup-form").hide(); 
});
```

And maybe if I want to validate the form I can use `.preventDefault();` in Jquery and do something. How does all this work in AngularJs?

Comment: Please see: [How do I “think in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14994391/1313143).

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms has information on validation..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the model value in your controller: `showConfirm = !showConfirm;`

This will update your view automatically using the `ng-hide` and `ng-show` directives you already have in place.

---

Better yet, call a scoped function like:

```
$scope.toggleConfirm = function() { showConfirm = !showConfirm; }
```

...and call that in your view using `ng-click="toggleConfirm()"` to keep your code [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).